# FusedLocationProvider - precise location and wifi

Tags: android, gps, location

Is it normal that using High Precision geolocation services with FusedLocationProvider API keeps "asking" (resolve errors dialog) users to turn on WiFi even if they are using cellular connection?
If thats normal flow - why does Google need that ? Isn't it a bug in FusedLocation API - should I file a bug report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fused location provider uses GPS, wifi, and cellular network info to determine your location.  Basically with wifi it does a scan and sees what SSIDs are around it.  Using that data it looks up where in the world it knows those SSIDs exist.  That can be used to determine a location within a few hundred meters.  The hard part is getting that data, but that's part of what their street view trucks do.

Note that you don't need to be connected to a wifi AP-  just have wifi turned on so it can scan.